# How can I ensure safety when literal passwords are required

Tags: password-management, server

I have a case at my hands where my server needs to make automated API calls that require authentication. Hence the server will need to know the literal passwords to make those calls.

What options do I have to ensure the security of those passwords?

Comment: Is the authentication method out of your control? A token based auth would be better. Preferably where the token only gives access to the bare minimum API calls. Make sure traffic is over SSL/TLS. Then in worst case scenario if your auth token is stolen, at least your password is still secure.

Comment: Sadly I have no control over the authentification or the APIs. Those are from third party providers.

Comment: It sounds like the question could be phrased as "How does a company like Mint safely store their customers' banking passwords?" - the answers for Mint would presumably apply for your use case as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store passwords in a retrievable way would probably be to encrypt them with a symmetric cipher.  Have the passwords stored on the device that intends to use them **only** in their encrypted form and then perhaps on startup of the service have the key to be used to decrypt the API passwords be derived through external methods (You yourself entering a password, retrieving it from an external computer not connected to the network, etc).

Once the key to decrypt your API passwords has been loaded into memory only and not placed on the disk, you may use it to decrypt the API passwords as needed.  Make sure to keep plaintext passwords in memory as well and overwrite them after they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is a literal password is this due to some api which required it once? Typically more modern forms of authentication bypass a direct password and one would redirect a user to a 3rd party authentication mechanism, along with an API key. The Ali provider would then pass back to your site an authentication token which you could use for API calls.

If it's a private password (eg. something similar to an SAP database), then you can simply lock down the file.

But if you are having to ask the user for their password directly so you can use some other backend code then that simply smells a bit funny to me and my gut would say there has to be some better way.

Comment: to give a little more context, its about "meta reporting". What I mean is that we have users who want to see their own data from several sources and we have to pool this data for them. Hence we receive credentials and have to use those for the authentification. Since we're talking about several APIs that we have to collect the data from, one API that requires a direct password already forces us to have them too.

Comment: And that direct password cannot be converted into a reusable token in any way shape or form ? I would contact the api author and try to see what can be done as I'm pretty sure that neither you or the third party content store really want to be in the news for potentially exposing user information.

Comment: I totally agree. In fact it makes me both sad and angry that there are too many people who do not care about this in a professional context. However the chance that they will adjust their system is rather slim. Hence the question in the first place. I as a developer want to have implemented as much security as possible given the situation. *sigh*

Comment: Have you actually tried to talk to the third party ? It's fairly easy to get email addresses and phone numbers of developers these days . I had a situation in the past few months where I had a chat with the tech lead for a large multi-national. They had a proprietary file format , no competing software could open their files, so I simply had a chat programmer to programmer, ( note I had never even heard of him until 10 minute prior even though I was more than aware of his company and software )... Lo and behold 2 hours later I had a email from him full of detailed documentation , and demo data

Comment: We are in contact with all the API providers. My assessment was base on my prior dealings with them. I will however try to stress the importance of the matter with my bosses. After all they would be the ones most directly affected by any bad press ;)

Comment: @Seba Is it a web service? Then using HTTPS with mutual certificate authentication would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a password in literal form is generally a bad idea.  If your hands are tied, try, at the very least, to compute the password on-the-fly using obfuscated code; this will at least thwart automated and low-level hackers should the binary be revealed.

Answer (score 0):

First of no solution will be at the level most often expected for password storage as you as a service will need access to the customer's passwords.

As you do not provide attack vectors yourself I'm going to assume you want to protect against the most common/easiest to achieve which would be DB access. (Read access in specific but for this situation it doesn't really matter.)

To protect against this encrypt the passwords before sending them to the DB-server and DO NOT store the encryption key in the DB or on the DB-server.
I would argue to have a server which only handles the encryption/decryption and API-calls. Then have as strong as possible firewall rules "around" it, ideally I would say to not have this server directly access the DB-server so as to limit it's communication to one other application server of yours and of course the access needed for the API calls.

This approach would make it so that an attacker will need to breach this encrypt/decrypt machine, and further will need to breach your DB (or other application server) if he wants to gain passwords for a specific user.
It also helps to focus your other protection measures around this server and code. Like code auditing of the application running on this server for example, another reason to keep the functionality of this application as limited as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the threat model or environment, I have to make assumptions what you want to guard against. I'm assuming your communication channel is secure and you worry about an attacker compromising the passwords on the server.

Firstly, harden your server properly. If wherever the passwords are stored is sufficiently protected with file permissions, stored in the proper inaccessible location, etc., you have already made the attackers life a lot more difficult.

Secondly, you can store the passwords encrypted, and either decrypt them on-the-fly or keep a decrypted copy in volatile memory. But this only moves the goalpost. If the attacker can get the password used to decrypt, or access the location where it's stored unencrypted, it's also game over.

Thirdly, if the password is never used directly, e.g. if the server needs to know it only to derive a session key, you could offload the whole thing to a secure module.

Fourthly, you could do your own man-in-the-middle and have a proxy inject the password. Again, this move the goalpost to the proxy server, and open a couple other cans of worms, but the proxy would probably be much less complex than your server and thus easier to harden.

tl;dr: There are a couple options, but you don't give enough specific information to come up with a really practical answer.